# Display user role in comments wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

So as my name suggests I am a complete newb. I want to create new user roles, assign them to some users and display user role in comments beside the username with normal subscriber not having any role shown.

I did see a thread regarding it [In wordpress How to display USER ROLE in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037576/in-wordpress-how-to-display-user-role-in-comments)

Being a complete newb I did not know where to paste the code posted in comments and whether to use the code submitted by the thread starter.

Please help, thanks

Comment: Your question mainly is where to put the code. So could you please provide some of your code so we can help you out?

Comment: Umm which code to provide? like should i post my coments.php code here?

Comment: All code that we need to help you out. So probably you could start with comments.php, yes.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fiWMefP2

Comment: That's my comment.php

Comment: I'll check it out soon. I have updated your post with the code so that maybe someone else will help you out before I found some time. :)

Comment: Alright I'll wait no problem:)

Comment: umm so anybody can help????

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help for you to display the role of the logged users.

```
global $wp_roles;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$roles = $current_user->roles;
$role = array_shift($roles);
```

This works for me.

Thanks